# CSS Menu appears behind jQuery Slideshow briefly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used some code from 2 sources to help me pretty up a page with both mega menus and a slideshow transition.  I made some changes to the jQ and the CSS to fit my needs.  I am having trouble with a flicker of sorts (particularly with Internet Explorer (9).  The Slideshow will appear to jump in front of the mega menu drop-down for a second and then go back. I don't think it is a z-index issue because it handles it; just not early enough. I put this into a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SeanPRyanKC/53RRy/.

The way I know to fix the issue is to not use a modern doctype and compatibility like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

if I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The page now works flawlessly but I lose my round corners and gradients etc.
Thanks

Comment: Check the below Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative; z-index:100;` to the `#menu li` properties.

If you watch the slideshow in Chrome Devtools or Firebug or whatever, when the slideshow image changes, it temporarily sets the z-index of the `<a>` tag to 10. So, to get rid of this problem, just set the z-index of the `<li>` higher than that.

Comment: Brilliant! I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add a new CSS

```
.slidesjs-control{z-index:-1}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/53RRy/9/

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I appreciate it. This worked for me as well.  When I mix the two suggestions, it is even better.  Cheers!